# How do I call a js function after I clicked on a particular date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How do I call a Javascript function once I clicked on a particular date in the datepicker?

I guess onSelect and onClose functions may do the trick, but I can't seem to make things work.

Thanks in advance.

For example:

What I wanted to do is to display the age in a different textbox based on the date selected in the datepicker. I already made the JS function that does that, but I do not know how to call it after clicking a date in the datepicker.

This JS function calculates age based on the date given.

```
// Calculates age based on birth date
function calAge() {
var now = new Date();
var bday = form1.elements['bday'].value;

bD = bday.split('/');
if (bD.length == 3) {
    born = new Date(bD[2], bD[1] * 1 - 1, bD[0]);
    years = Math.floor((now.getTime() - born.getTime()) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    form1.elements['age'].value = (years - 100);
}
```

}

This is the datepicker. Am I right in calling the JS function?

```
$(".datepicker2")
    .datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: calAge
    })
```

Comment: WHYTSF (please show us some code the best you tried so far)

Comment: you are right: onSelect would do the trick. See if you can find examples online to give you an idea on how to make yours work. Or, as Roko said, please show code so we can help with your particular situation.

Comment: It's quite easy http://jsfiddle.net/nBdt4/ - but without any code its like fortune telling :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialise your datepicker you can define an onSelect function like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ onSelect: function(date) {alert(date);}});
```

Here's a simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7jTNL/

Answer (score 0):

Bind the change event to the input.

```
$("#theInput")    .datepicker({params...})
                  .change(function(e){
                       //what you want to happen when a date is changed.
                  })
```